# Can spirits Endow their Immunity?

Tags: powers, shadowrun-sr5, shadowrun, spirits

If a spirit has the Endowment power, can they share their Immunity to Age/Normal Weapons? Excluding Hidden Life/Spirit Pact, are there any other ways for characters to gain the benefits of these abilities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A spirit can't **Endow** a power it doesn't actually have. No spirits have **Immunity to Age** and no spirit any sane metahuman would want to be involved with has **Immunity to Normal Weapons**.

- **Materialization** spirits only receive it *when* materialized; they don't have it naturally.
- **Possession** spirits don't grant it via any means.
- **Inhabitation** grants it via Hybrid Form or Flesh Form merges... and no rational person wants to become a filthy bug spirit. True Form merges become Materialization spirits.

The only spirit that actually gets **Endowment** is a Great Form. In theory, a Great Hybrid Form Insect Spirit or a Great Flesh Form Insect Spirit could **Endow** somebody with **Immunity to Normal Weapons**, but you wouldn't want to be beholden to such an entity, nor the Insect Shaman or Queen that controls it. Besides, it'd make you harder to eat.

A character could get **Immunity to Age** by being exposed to HMHVV-I (or Ia) and becoming one of the **Infected** (Run Faster, p. 133-). Banshees, Dzoo-Noo-Qua, Goblins, Mutaqua, Nosferatu, Vampires, and Wendigo all get it. The HMHVV-II species and Ghouls (HHMVV-III) don't grant it.

Comment: Where does it actually say that **Endow** can only grant powers, that they *naturally* have? The exact words are "one of its powers"? IMHO it's vague enough to be up to the GM interpretation and personally as GM I wouldn't allow this, but are there any rules that definitely say it's not possible that the spirit endows the power while materialized?